# Palette FutureWarning using Seaborn and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need some help. I am running this bar plot using Seaborn and Matplotlib:

```
sns.barplot(x=star_df['Star color'].value_counts().index, 
            y=star_df['Star color'].value_counts(),
            palette='viridis')
plt.title('Visualizing the Count of Star Colors', color='purple', fontweight='bold')
plt.xticks(color='orange')
plt.ylabel('Star color', color='orange', fontsize=13)
plt.show()
```

I am getting this warning however:
:3: FutureWarning:

Passing `palette` without assigning `hue` is deprecated and will be removed in v0.14.0. Assign the `x` variable to `hue` and set `legend=False` for the same effect.

```
sns.barplot(x=star_df['Star color'].value_counts().index
```

Kindly help me on how I can fix this.

Comment: It is recommended to store the counts dataframe separately: `star_df_counts = star_df['Star color'].value_counts()` and then set `hue=` to the same as used for `x=`. So `ax = sns.barplot(x=star_df_counts.index, y=star_df_counts, hue=star_df_counts.index, palette='viridis')`.  The idea is that `palette=` is only used when also `hue=` is used.